# Is it save to move the start sector of the c drive

Tags: gparted

I wanted to merge a unallocated partition behind of the C: drive with gparted but when I resize the C: drive it says “You have queued an operation to move the start sector of /dev/sda4. Failure to boot is most likely to occur if you move the gnu/linux partition containing /boot, or if you move the windows system partition C:.” And I don’t want to lose any data

Comment: Short answer is a big NO.  Do not try moving partitions unless all your data is back up.  Should also have flash installers ready for both windows and ubuntu.  Moving and/or changing partitions can be done if you know what you are doing and have backups.  Can use google to find site explaining how to do it.  Here is one link,  https://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dhelp-manual

Comment: If you're going to resize an NTFS partition (C: drive) you should use Windows own `Disk Management` app. Use `gparted` for everything else. Also, without seeing a screenshot of `gparted`, we can only guess what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: From an Ubuntu terminal window, please run `sudo gparted -l` . Copy the result, come back here, click [edit] and paste the result into your question so we can see what you have.

Comment: Some more information to read.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/299886/partitions-is-it-safe-to-move-partition-containing-boot?rq=1